# Splitting string into multiple columns based on symbol

Tags: r, string, split

I have one column in a dataframe that contains either a four digit number (e.g. 4567), a five digit number (19282), a four and a five digit number separated by a slash (e.g. 16726/2625 or 8728/16292) or two five digit number separated by a slash (e.g. 37647/38838). I want to split the values in this column into different columns that contain only the four digit number, the first five digit number or the second 5 digit number.

I have tried to do it with stringsplit but I did not succeed

This is what I have:

```
da <-data.frame(x=c("12345/6789","9876", "23456", "75648/38292", "3456", "98765/1234", "6543", "67898"))
```

This is what I need:

```
db <-data.frame(x=c("12345/6789","9876", "23456", "75648/38292", "3456", "98765/1234", "6543", "67898"), four_digit_a=c(6789, 9876, NA, NA, 3456, 1234,6543, NA), five_digit_a=c(12345,NA, 23456,75648, NA, 98765, NA, 67898), five_digit_b=c(NA, NA, NA, 38292, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Comment: Please check your example.  It is giving me error while copy/pasting

Comment: `I have tried to do it with stringsplit but I did not succeed` Could you share what you have tried?

Comment: in your example, `da` and `db` are identical...

Comment: Sorry, of course, I only had the first column in da!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tidyr` and `dplyr` do to this, first split the data on the `/` and then use the lengths of the first element and second element to group them into `four_digit_a`, `five_digit_a` or `five_digit_b`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


df <-data.frame(x=c("12345/6789","9876", "23456", "75648/38292", "3456", "98765/1234", "6543", "67898")) %>%
  separate(x, into = c('first','second'), sep = '/') %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(four_digit_a = ifelse(nchar(first) == 4, first, NA)) %>%
  mutate(five_digit_a = ifelse(nchar(first) == 5, first, NA)) %>%
  mutate(five_digit_b = ifelse(nchar(second) == 5, second, NA))
```

Which will give you:

```
  first second four_digit_a five_digit_a five_digit_b
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
1 12345 6789   NA           12345        NA          
2 9876  NA     9876         NA           NA          
3 23456 NA     NA           23456        NA          
4 75648 38292  NA           75648        38292       
5 3456  NA     3456         NA           NA          
6 98765 1234   NA           98765        NA          
7 6543  NA     6543         NA           NA          
8 67898 NA     NA           67898        NA
```

(Note these numbers are now `character` instead of `numeric` since the input data was `character` so you have to convert these to `numeric` if you want to use the "numbers" in calculations)